# Highlights with hair

Tags: materials, particles, image

Well the question is simple in blender there's hair particle tools and there's a lot of videos on how to work with it. But I haven't seen videos on coloring, painting or dyeing hair in blender.

So I want to ask If I have my blender hair completely red can I give it some small black red highlights and a big yellow highlight?

If I can how?

Comment: You can use a texture to determine the hair color using *from dupli* texture coordinates.

Comment: Related answer: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18970/how-to-change-hair-color-along-length-of-strand

Answer (score 4):

If you use Cycles, there is a node called Hair Info. You can use the intercept value (Gives a gradient where the root of the hair is black and tip is white) from it to achieve a gradient along the length of the hair. You could for example run it through a ColorRamp. (For more info on hair rendering, see the Wiki here: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:UK/2.6/Manual/Render/Cycles/Hair_Rendering). There is also an excellent video on hair rendering by Andrew Price, see here: http://youtu.be/jEnCsvcvX8k.

Answer (score 3):

The colour of the hair is defined by the material chosen in the render settings for the particle system. By default this is the same material used for the surface of the emitter but you can select a different material if you want.

[image]

To get parts of the hair a different colour you can either use a noise texture to mix between colours or you can paint an image texture to control where the colour changes.

Answer (score 0):

What you probably need to do, is duplicate your emitter object. Essentially you have 3 separate hair systems. 1 for each color.

I think most of the answers above relate to coloring different colours along the strand, but if you want multiple patches or sections, I think you have to separate the hair systems.

Comment: Actually, you can use a texture to do this, the strand will take the colour of that texture at the position it is emitted.