# hair particle textures

Tags: texturing, particles

any way to texture hair particles mid strand? like have brown hair with white frosted tips or a pink star in the middle?

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35403/highlights-with-hair/35417#35417

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/18970/599

Comment: If I understand what you want, yes. Please give some sort of reference or more information.

Comment: Thx I'll give those a try otherwise I will try to build an example I what I need if these don't do what I need - though these answers should work. Thx vm for the help and answers.